# How to deploy a contract with linked libraries and a different version in `foundry test`

Tags: contract-deployment, testing, library, foundry, forge

I need to deploy a contract with an incompatible version number to my test script. The natural solution is to use deployCode, however, this contract also requires certain libraries. The following leads to an error:

address factory = deployCode(
“Factory.sol”,
abi.encode(arg1)
);

Error:

```
[FAIL. Reason: Setup failed: No bytecode for contract. Is it abstract or unlinked?]
```

It's a known limitation that deployCode doesn't support library linking which prevents the Factory contract from being deployed.

What is the best alternative for deploying a contract that needs a unique version number and depends on libraries?

I know I could manually change the version numbers in the contract with linked libraries to comply but there is a very large/nested number of contracts involved that would have to be changed (>10).